# Twitter like DB lookup's in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm planning to use mongoDB for a twitter like app. Where you can get all the messages from people you follow.

The best I can come up with is something like this:

```
Collections:
Users
Following
Messages
```

Every time you refresh your feed you will have to get a list of who you follow. Then query Messages with an array of everyone maybe 1000 id's.

Is there a better way to do this? Would I be better of using a relational database?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. The one you described is good for starting. When/if you start feeling pain, you'll know how you need to change it. :)

Comment: I would like doing it "the right" way the first time. In stead of having to redesign the whole thing later

Comment: There's no one universal right way.